# OpenTelemetry exporter logs/errors in AWS Lambda, Invalid type NoneType for attribute, Invalid type <class 'NoneType'> of value None, etc

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, open-telemetry

Context:

I'm using a couple of tools to send metrics from an AWS Lambda function to the ADOT collector. Overall, I deployed my API service (FastAPI) with AWS Lambda.

Tools:

1. AWS Lambda
2. Python==3.9
3. opentelemetry-sdk==1.17.0
4. `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-python-amd64-ver-1-17-0:1` ([AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry Lambda Support](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda/lambda-python))

Basically, I'm sending my metrics to the local ADOT collector, and the collector is exporting them to my exporter endpoint.

Problem:

The problem is I see a couple of logs inside the lambda log group, and I cannot figure out how I should do:

1. Disable these logs
2. Fix those problems

These are environment variables to configure the OTEL in the Lambda:

```bash
AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER=/opt/otel-instrument
OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE=/var/task/src/otel-config.yaml
OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=otlp
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=http/protobuf
OPENTELEMETRY_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL=error
```

This is the `otel-config.yaml` file:

```yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: https://<ANOTHER_SERVICE>:4317

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

Here are some logs that I'm receiving in the log group:

```bash
[WARNING]   2023-05-01T23:56:03.374Z        An instrument with name http.server.duration, type Histogram, unit ms and description measures the duration of the inbound HTTP request has been created already.
```

[image]

```bash
[ERROR] 2023-05-01T23:56:04.958Z    42a36f0d-6bde-428d-833a-fc34f295a4a9    Failed to export batch code: 404, reason: 404 page not found
```

Note that everything is working as expected, and I can see the metrics in the Grafana dashboard, but these errors are making logs hard to maintain.

Comment: I'm getting the same [ERROR] line as yours and its driving me crazy. Can't figure out what is causing it. Using ADOT Otel for Python Lambda 1.16.0 with Python3.8

Comment: @RobertJBerger I finally managed to remove/resolve almost all of these logs. Let me know what kind of errors you are getting. Here is my issue/discussion in GitHub: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/1780